# Buscar Array com determinadas características

Tags: javascript, array, canvas

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um game bem básico com Javascript, porém me deparei com uma coisinha que não consegui resolver até o momento, a questão seria, tenho um Array, no qual incluo aleatoriamente 28 objetos, e esses objetos possuem uma posição **x**, **y** e **color**, os quais também são determinados aleatoriamente, ao preencher este Array, eles são exibidos através do elemento **<canvas>**, o que eu estaria tentando fazer, seria, verificar se os elementos estão alinhados na tela(em grupos de 3 ou mais) e remove-los do Array principal, como as posições são determinadas aleatoriamente, os elementos podem estar sendo exibidos segundo a ordem em que estão guardados no Array ou não

Ex:

[image: Screenshot Game]

os cubos verdes na imagem seguem o padrão, tipo naqueles joguinhos antigos, tenho um "demo" no [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Russo/pen/awzmJq), espero ter conseguido explicar

Comment: Tem como descrever melhor o que seriam os elementos alinhados em grupos?

Comment: como na imagem acima, três elementos de mesma cor formaram uma combinação em tela, tipo  a posição do item 1 é `{x: 40, y: 0, color: 'green'}` no item 2 `{x: 40, y: 40, color: 'green'}` e item 3 `{x: 40, y: 80, color: 'green'}`  imaginando que fosse um plano cartesiano, estes três itens estariam alinhados na vertical, imagina um array cheio de itens com estas mesmas características, o que eu queria fazer seria remover todos os que entrem neste padrão(3 itens ou mais) se a cor deles for igual, levando em consideração, os itens alinhados na horizontal e na vertical